# taking snapshots - is there a way for drawImage & toDataURL to preserve filters?

Tags: css, html5-video, html5-canvas

I have a video element with filters chosen by a user applied to it. As I try to take a snapshot of it, the filters applied to the video are not applied to the snapshot:

```
// live is a video element and snapshot is a canvas
function onTakeSnapshot() {

    // Make the canvas the same size as the video
    snapshot.width = live.clientWidth;
    snapshot.height = live.clientHeight;
    // Draw a frame of the live video onto the canvas
    var c = snapshot.getContext("2d");
    c.drawImage(live, 0, 0, snapshot.width, snapshot.height);
    snapshot.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

I realise that I can apply the same filter to the snapshot, for example, `snapshot.className='';snapshot.classList.add('grayscale');` but then I run into the same issue saving it to disk, i.e. `var img = snapshot.toDataURL();` results in image without any of the filters applied to it. I currently manipulate the image separately using `getImageData()\putImageData()` but results are often different from the canvas+filter. I am new to canvas and was wondering if there is a way to draw and save the images with filters already applied. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to take a screenshot of a web page in the browser which your question implies.

I suggest you push all filtering code through `<canvas>` if you need to save the result.

Comment: Mikko, thanks for your answer. However, if I try to push things through canvas, as in filtering the snapshot canvas: `snapshot.className='';snapshot.classList.add('grayscale');`, I still get the original image when I do `var img = snapshot.toDataURL();`. Either I am not getting something simple or there is no way of doing what I am trying to do. It just seems counter-intuitive for such a great feature as canvas not to give access to what it is putting out on the screen. It must be stored somewhere!

Comment: Canvas pixel contents and whatever your website CSS effect composition get are totally different things. That was I tried to tell you. **Do effects on canvas pixel level using canvas API if you want to store them**

Comment: You mean the way I was doing it already with `getImageData()\putImageData()`? So your answer to my question seems to be "no". I don't understand why that's the case and so far I'm going with it's a shortcoming of the API.

Comment: If you do web effects on CSS they do not affect the values of canvas pixels. It is not API shortcoming, it is designed like that for many reasons (security, web page composition, how browsers work, etc.)